# pasar datos del usuario por medio de un modal

Tags: html, laravel

Estoy haciendo un crud con `laravel`, estoy implementando un modal para editar mi usuario pero necesito que en ese modal se carguen los `datos` del usuario, el codigo que tengo es el siguiente

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <span class="custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                            <label for="selectAll"></label>
                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th>Nombre de Usuario</th>
                    <th>Contraseña</th>
                    <th>Rol</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($lista as $d)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
                            <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ $d->usuario }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $d->password }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $d->rol }}</td>
                    <td>

                        <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                        <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach

            </tbody>
        </table>
<div id="editEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form>
                <div class="modal-header">                      
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Editar Usuario</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Usuario</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Rol</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" required></textarea>
                    </div>          
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de abrir el modal los datos se carguen automaticamente, como podria pasar el id , lo hice en ocaciones pasadas pasandole el id por medio de la ruta, estoy usando un controlador `resource` y con el `show` le enviaba los datos a unos input, pero en este caso no se por que lado irme para realizarlo.

Gracias.

Comment: Utiliza javascript

Comment: quieres que se carguen en el modal o que el modal llame a los datos a una tabla afuera?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo mediante `ajax`... Al botón **editar** le creas un atributo que se llame `idUsuario` y le asignas `idUsuario="{{ $d->idUsuario }}"`. En tu `modal` agregas los atributos `id`, `name` y `value` a cada `input`, `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="editarUsuario" name="editarUsuario" value="" required>`. Capturas el `idUsuario` al hacer click en el botón y haces la petición `ajax`. Finalmente, enviás la respuesta a los `value` de cada `input`... Podría pasarte un ejemplo con `php` ya que desconozco `laravel`. comenta si te interesa.